# How do I stack the buttons in an Alert window vertically in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex3, alert

I have an Alert dialog in which the 4 buttons have somewhat lengthy labels. 
This Alert dialog then takes up the entire width of the screen which is rather odd. Is it possible, and if so how, to display the buttons vertically.

I have researched the flex Alert docs and a few other sites to no avail.

Comment: Which version of Flex?

Comment: Flex 3.5 (build 12683) @Brian

Comment: I think in that case you'll have to roll your own using PopupManager and mx:TitleWindow.  As an aside, why don't you use Flex 4.6 or later?  It's nearly 4 years old already!

Comment: I would very much like to avoid that ( I ended up just modifying the Alert Title & message so that I could use shorter/simpler labels, probably what I should have done in the first place ). We are going to develop our application on a different platform soon. I'm guessing that my company does not want to spend the time updating all the source code since we are going in that direction. Thank you for replying @Brian